# android button above keyboard with just a scrollview and relativeview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this code

```
<ScrollView>
<RelativeView>
...
</RelativeView>
</Scrolview>
```

is it possible to make a button float on top of keyboard, without having to change to

```
<RelativeView>
<button />
<ScrollView>
     <RelativeView>
     </RelativeView>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeView>
```

because as android reccomends, the less layers and views the better for performance

Comment: create a outer linear layout and then button and then scrollview what u suggested. abd add adjustResize in manifest for your activity. this will make your entire view scrollable. and if any problem post here. And no if u don't want button to float u have to put that button out of scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

Use `adjustResize` or `adjustPan` in your manifest.xml file like this:

```
<application
      android:icon="@drawable/icon"
      android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <activity
                .....
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
                <intent-filter >
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               </intent-filter>
       </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: tried both with button android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and android:layout_below="@+id/...", didn't work